# pretty url not working

Tags: .htaccess, yii2, friendly-url, yii2-advanced-app

Below is my `main.php`

```
 'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [  '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                       '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                       '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',               
                    ],
        ],
```

I have enabled pretty url (i think), i am getting a lot of 404's, like

`192.168.1.3/~user/urshow/frontend/web/movies/movies_all` it would have work fine if it would be like this `192.168.1.3/~user/urshow/frontend/web/index.php?r=movies/movies_all`
and no links are working which worked perfect previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my .htacess file which is inside my project's web folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~user/urshow/frontend/web/
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

my main.php file inside config

```
 'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
         'rules' => array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
    ],
```

this worked for me .

Answer (score 2):

Try this...
create `.htaccess` file in your root folder
and add following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

May help you..

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work. . .

```
192.168.1.3/~user/urshow/frontend/web/index.php/movies/movies_all
```

Put this code in `common/config/main.php`

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [  '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                   '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                   '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',               
                ],
    ],
```

Comment: i tried it but not working i got lot's of error in console like -                                          GET http://192.168.1.3/~user/urshow/frontend/web/index.php/theatres/city/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js 404 (Not Found) 2:12
GET http://192.168.1.3/~user/urshow/frontend/web/index.php/theatres/city/css/style.css 404 (Not Found) 2:30

Comment: you use ~user and urshow before frontend in your url, are you sure it worked with route (r=)??

I mean, as I know url in yii2 would be like - localhostaddress/projectName/backendOrFrontend/web/index.php -

Comment: sorry my working url is this- 192.168.1.3/~user/urshow/frontend/web/index.php?r=movies/movies_all

Comment: sorry then :) , I have no Idea to solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

create a .htaccess file and place it in your project folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Now in your web.php add the following in the components section:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        // Disable index.php
        'showScriptName' => false,
        // Disable r= routes
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),
        ],
```

this will definitely work.

Comment: I agree, this should work, though the .htaccess file should not be placed in the project folder but inside the web/ folder of the application, where your index.php file is

Comment: it didn't work. i got error like this- unable to resolve request ~user/urshow/frontend/web/movies/movies_all

Comment: where did you place the .htaccess file?

Comment: i placed in urshow folder(my application folder). i got error like this Unable to resolve the request "~user/urshow/frontend/web/movies/movies_all". if put index.php after /web it will work. its just 'index.php' which is not working

Comment: replace this with the last line of .htaccess file RewriteRule . ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [PT,L,QSA] hope this work well

Answer (score -1):

add below statement on router config to make html5 true.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
```

then add settings on web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="AngularJS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```